# How can I install the file libc.a using " dnf install " in centos8

Tags: c

In centos8, I compiled c file like this, but wrong:

```
# LANG=C gcc -static pointer.c   -o pointer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And if remove "-static", it is ok.

In Ubuntu-20.04, Both with and without "-statis" are Ok. I found libc.a in Ubuntu:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

"libc.a" Installed by command in Ubuntu-20.04 :

```
apt install libc6-dev
```

In centos8,
How can I install the file libc.a using " dnf install " ?

I've tried:

```
# dnf install glibc-static
Last metadata expiration check: 1:36:14 ago on Thu Aug 26 16:13:42 2021.
No match for argument: glibc-static
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-static

# dnf config-manager --enable 
# dnf install glibc-static
Last metadata expiration check: 1:36:26 ago on Thu Aug 26 16:13:42 2021.
No match for argument: glibc-static
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-static
```

**EDIT:**

*Resolved by:*

```
# dnf --enablerepo=powertools install glibc-static
```

ref links:

https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/glibc-static-2.28-151.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: `apt install` on CentOS? I doubt that...

Comment: @andreee `apt install libc6-dev` is from Ubuntu and the question is about doing the same in Centos.

Comment: @acodebang have you tried [this](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-find-which-rpm-package-provides-a-specific-file-or-library-in-rhel-centos/) to find which package provides the file?

Comment: @SimonDoppler: My bad, I overlooked that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are missing the static glibc libraries, which are not installed by default.
In CentOS, install them with

```
dnf install glibc-static
```

This should work.

Excerpt from `dnf info glibc-static`:

> Description  : The glibc-static package contains the C library static libraries
> for -static linking.  You don't need these, unless you link statically,
> which is highly discouraged.

---

*Note: In case you don't see the package, you may have to add the "PowerTools" repo:*

```
dnf config-manager --enable PowerTools
```

*See also [this link](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/glibc-static-2.28-151.el8.x86_64.rpm.html).*

Comment: # dnf install glibc-static
Last metadata expiration check: 1:29:02 ago on Thu Aug 26 16:13:42 2021.
No match for argument: glibc-static
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-static

Comment: Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-static